# Why is it when I update an entry within a structure in the admin, it reorders it to the bottom of the list?

Tags: craft3, structure, admin

I've created a structure and I have about 15 entries in it. They are grouped under an entry named "0234" and each entry below it is named 0234 A, 0234 B, 0234 C, etc. I would like to keep them in this order but if I edit 0234 B and save it, it re-orders it to the bottom.

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing a configuration option somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It's not intended behaviour when you're editing an existing entry, and it can't be changed - because it's not meant to be doing it. I noticed this on a site last week, but I can't replicate it right now.
I think it'd be worth filing a bug report on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought it was strange. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: For posterity, this was fixed in 3.4.25 https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/7af2a900dc0fa20725fb949ffda672040d2a97ae